# Power analysis for spatially structured variables in survival analysis

Tags: survival, spatial, epidemiology

I am working with colleagues on an analysis of survival in a chronic neurological disease. There are several well known factors that influence survival. We have data from a good register which includes these. We are doing an analysis looking at spatial variation in survival - specifically we want to know if survival is related to the level of affluence in the small area in which our patients live.

There are a whole bunch of technical issues here, with which we are tolerably familiar, but we are struggling with one.

How do we estimate the power of our study to detect the effect on survival, if any, of a spatially structured covariate.

We have a survival model, and we have reasonable power for the usual covariates, age, sex, mode of presentation, and so on. We are struggling with power analysis for variables like distance from the urban centre, small area socio-economic group and so on. For all of these variables there is sizeable spatial auto-correlation. We can measure this easily enough also.

I'm assuming that the most practical way to do the power analysis is to use simulation, which is what we did for the other variables. I'm struggling with the mechanics of doing this for spatially co-varying variables. There are a few papers on simulation based power analysis for cluster detection methods, but none seem to fit our issues.

Any suggestions - any papers you can point us to? Or am I making a mountain out of a molehill?

Regards,
Anthony Staines

Comment: My approach in situations like this is to estimate bounds - for example, how many geographic units do you have? Using those as the unit of analysis would give you a lower bound, while ignoring the spatial auto-correlation would give you an upper bound. This is a very interesting problem, and I look forward to seeing what suggestions you get.